# Add line to comment in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax, formatting

I'm looking for something rather specific.

Let's say I define something like a variable, and add a comment to it.

```
#define ARDUINO_READ_Q0 //Read pins 22-29
```

Now, any time I start typing ARDUINO_READ_Q0, it pops up in Visual Studio's list of available values, and when you hover over it, it comes up with a tooltip saying "Read pins 22-29"

Is there any way to add a line to this tooltip? I thought of something like this:

```
#define ARDUINO_READ_Q0 /* Read pins 22-29
                           Return 1B */
```

However, I would prefer for it to remain on a single line when I define it.

To give you an idea of what I'm trying to do, imagine something looking like this:

```
#define ARDUINO_READ_Q0 // Read pins 22-29  /n  Return 1B
```

This way I can say "next line" without making the mess of having two lines per #define.

It's sort of a formatting preference. I'm about to have a lot of #defines.

Comment: Have you tried it using `\n` (not /n) like in your example or with a trailing \ after the line?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2013 there are special XML tags that you can use to do this.

```
/// <summary>Read pins 22-29</summary>
#define ARDUINO_READ_Q0
```

This will display "Read pins 22-29" in the Intellisense tooltip when you hover the `ARDUINO_READ_Q0`.

You can find more documentation details on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177227.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177226.aspx

---

Note: This may work on older version of Visual Studio but I only have 2013 have on my laptop at the moment.